# Ruby on Rails 3 search external website source based on top google result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I'm having a hard time finding out where to start with this one. I pull information from an external website and put some of the content on my page. I think I need two things done. 1. A google search that takes the url of the top search given a name of my current object. 2. A way to examine the source of the result and output the information of a tag with a specific class.

To better explain this, I'll create a hypothetical situation: Say I have a website that lists mattresses and gives reviews. Say I want to add other websites reviews and in this website there's a tag like 3.5/5. Then I want to display this review along with a link to the external page. Is there a way to search the site like "site:http://mattressreviewsite/ @matress.name", pull that top url, and then search the source for the string "class='rating'" and display this in my view?

Thanks for any help or guidance. I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need an HTTP client (httparty, net/http-default) for that and do some parsing to get the required results.

Go study the url patterns of google (as far as I remember it was google.com?q=search_string) and use the http client for requests (get/post). Parse the result (there are many HTML parser gems available too) to get what you need and for any subsequent HTTP requests. And don't forget the 'I am feeling lucky' feature of google which returns only one result.

All the best!